# redux in "vector class redux"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary

I encounter the word "redux" in "Vector Class Redux" when reading the book "fluent python", 
[image]

In [redux | Definition of redux in English by Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/redux)

> redux
>   adjective [ after noun ] UK ​  /ˈriː.dʌks/ US ​  /ˈriː.dʌks/
>   ​
>   (often used in the titles of films and video games) brought back:
>   With "Ashes of Time Redux," Wong has decided to recut and rethink his original material.

The definition helps little to understand it,
google does not helps when searching vector redux

what does it mean here?

Comment: As the dictionary says, it mean that the author is "bringing back" the topic Vector Class for further discussion.

Comment: Could you please transmit the post to answer, thank you. @StoneyB

Comment: I do not answer questions about technical English unless I have familiarity with the technical topic. But it appears here that the author simply means to work again with an example used earlier for a different purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question - indeed, "redux" likely means *to return to*, or *to revisit* the subject known as a vector class in the excerpt you posted, as many others have supported.

Additionally, when used in this context it also implies that this new discussion will make adjustments or modifications to the prior approach or description of the topic (i.e. "vector class"), or is bringing the concept back after originally being removed (hence definitions of "redux" usually including "revived" or "brought back" in them).

*However*, one particularly important note: these interpretations of "redux" work well in the knowledge that this segment comes from a book intended to teach and impart knowledge about the Python programming language, and that it appears to be a full discussion revolving around the "vector class." Since you appear to be studying programming though, it may be useful to know that there are other cases where the term "redux" appears, and is used as a name to describe a type of object instead of to imply a new discussion or revisitation. For example, "Redux" is a javascript container meant for predictable state apps (see resource [here](https://redux.js.org/)). I am unaware of others, but I believe this is a good example of how asking around for clarification can be useful!

Hope this helps, and please let me know if further clarification would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

"Redux" is a fancy way to say that the author is going to *revisit* a subject previously talked about.  In this case it means that the book previously talked about the vector class, and now it's going to talk about it again.   I would expect the book to provide other examples of how it can be useful, related to all the in-between material.